# Cant assign response to a result object

Tags: node.js

I have an api from Twilo that I am trying to use to get some data from there API.
I can print the result to console but for some reason i cant assign the phone_number response to the result and return it.

```
then(phone_number => result = phone_number)
```

What am i missing here ?

```
apiRoutes.get('/callerid/:number', async (req, res) => {
  let result
  client.lookups.v1.phoneNumbers(req.params.number)
      .fetch({type: ['carrier', 'caller-name']})
      .then(phone_number => console.log(phone_number)
      );

  console.log(result)
  res.json({ Success: true , Data: result })

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to save the whole promise in the `result` variable

you must return `phone_number` in the last `then`

```
apiRoutes.get('/callerid/:number', async (req, res) => {

  let result = await client.lookups.v1.phoneNumbers(req.params.number)
      .fetch({type: ['carrier', 'caller-name']})
      .then(phone_number => phone_number);

  console.log(result)
  res.json({ Success: true , Data: result })

})
```